# How to forbid edition of arguments of a function, expect Array.reduce accumulator

Tags: eslint, typescript-eslint, eslintrc, eslint-config-airbnb

I did not find a documentation in the whole eslint website, and I do not know if there is a plugin to forbid arguments editions.

Here is an example of code which should be:

**Incorrect**:

```js
const incorrectUpdate = (data) => {
  data.field = data.field === 'Hello' ? 'Stack' : 'Overflow';
  return data;
};
```

**Correct:**

```js
const validUpdate = (data) => {
  return { ...data, field: data.field === 'Hello' ? 'Stack' : 'Overflow' };
};
```

Please can you send me the eslint config?

Can you left Array.reduce to continue accumulator edition ?

Comment: Assuming I've understood "arguments editions" correctly, and you mean mutating the parameter values, [`no-param-reassign`](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-param-reassign) can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activate `no-param-reassign`.

For Array.reduce, use every time the same variable name: `"acc"`.

Here is the config, in `.eslintrc`:

```json
"no-param-reassign": [
  "warn",
  {
    "props": true,
    "ignorePropertyModificationsFor": ["acc"]
  }
],
```